# Xpath current date

Tags: date, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage where a row displays name, relation and date. I want to search for the matching row as per my values. Using Xpath, I have built the below mentioned code. The only problem is the last part (the date). I want to pick up the current date and fit it into the search query..i.e. instead of 30 Sep 2013, I want it to search for 01 Oct 2013 (assuming today is this date).
Any clue how can i do that??

```
$x('//tr[descendant::b[text()="text1"] and descendant::a[@class="bill" and text()="for Automation"] and descendant::td[text()="30 Sep 2013"]]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the expression dynamically and append the date string at the end based on some date object. The specific implementation depends on which programming language you're using

Comment: yeah..got that right now :)..used var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");...and appended +today+ in the Xpath...Somehow I cannot answer my own question within 8 hours of posting my question...but thanks for your input..Appreciated..